# Retrieve data from firebase using unique id

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Actually I retrieve data from firebase with marker click listener. Each data has unique id. [image: marker for Care medical center in]

So when I click **care Medical Center in** then it goes to another window and another window is given below:
[image: Another window for hospital information]

But when i click sust medical then it goes to same window and same data.

Actually main this is same data.
How can i retrieve the different data for another marker.

Hare is my firebase:[image]

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_h_info);

        hosp_name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.hosp_name);
        hosp_email=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.hosp_email);
        hosp_num=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.hosp_number);

        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference1=firebaseDatabase.getReference("H_Information");

        databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    hosp_name.setText(dataSnapshot1.child("hname").getValue().toString());
                    hosp_email.setText(dataSnapshot1.child("hemail").getValue().toString());
                    hosp_num.setText(dataSnapshot1.child("hmobile").getValue().toString());


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Above code retrieve data but your not showing about onclick events or anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a query to retrieve the correct data, for example you can use the `equalTo()`:

```
        databaseReference1.orderByChild("hname").equalTo("sust medical").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    hosp_name.setText(dataSnapshot1.child("hname").getValue().toString());
                    hosp_email.setText(dataSnapshot1.child("hemail").getValue().toString());
                    hosp_num.setText(dataSnapshot1.child("hmobile").getValue().toString());


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

When you click on sust medical, then take the name and pass it to as an argument in `equalTo()`

Comment: This ok but when i click new marker then how can i retrieve data from H_information from firebase

Comment: When you click on the new marker, use the query equal to, so you can retrieve the information related to that marker

Comment: When you click on sust medical(new marker) , then take the name and pass it to as an argument in equalTo()